# Calculate these integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to know how to calculate any of these integrals, which arise from computing the perimeter of the unit ball in the $p$-norm.

1. $$\int_0^1(1+p^pt^{p(p-1)})^{1/p} dt;$$
2. $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos(t)^{2-p}\sin(t)^2+\sin(t)^{2-p}\cos(t)^2)^{1/p} dt.$$

In the first one, I tried to expand $(1+p^pt^{p(p-1)})^{1/p}$ as
$$\sum_{k =0}^\infty \binom{1/p}{k}(pt^{p(p-1)})^k,$$
where $\binom{1/p}{k} = \frac{(1/p)\cdots((1/p)-k+1)}{k!}$.

Since
$$\int_0^1 t^{p(p-1)k} dt = \frac{t^{1+p(p-1)k}}{1+p(p-1)k} = \frac{1}{1+p(p-1)k},$$

it follows that
$$\int_0^1(1+p^pt^{p(p-1)})^{1/p} dt = \sum_{0}^\infty \binom{1/p}{k}\frac{p^{pk}}{1+p(p-1)k}.$$

I'm not sure if this converges and how to calculated it. I don't know how to proceed in the second one.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but is it really necessary? I just want to calculate these and move on, but I can't find it anywhere, so I figured someone here could give me a hand.

Comment: On MSE, we do not answer problem-statement-questions. We are not here to do your homework for you. So, yes it is really necessary if you want an answer. Give the integrals a shot, show us what you did, then you'll get an answer.

Comment: I want to calculate the perimeter of a the unit ball in the p-norm, that's it. These integrals come from two different ways I found of parameterizing the curves.

Comment: These integrals are already simplified. I got some constants out etc. I thought about expanding the first in series and integrating after that, but I'm not sure if it converges.

Comment: In the second one, I tried to factorize it as $\cos^2\sin^2(\cos^{-p}+\sin^{-p})$, but I'm not sure if this is going to help.

Comment: This is not homework, it's just a problem I'm trying to figure out. I'm not trying to cheat or anything, so you could be a little less indelicate. I don't really understand how MSE works. I've posted 3 questions before, explaining everything, how I tried to solve it, etc. Only one of them got an answer, 1 answer; the other. silence... So I figured people just didn't want to read all the blablabla. Now I come here and ask a simple question about integrals, and I supposed to explain it. I really don't mean to be rude, I just don't get it.

Comment: I added some of the calculations I've done.

Comment: I’ve upvoted your post; when you say calculate the perimeter of the unit ball, do you mean surface area? Or do you mean the length of a great circle in the $p$-norm? I’m not sure I understand totally.

Comment: Also, I’d add that the questions you’re asking are relatively technical. That may be why they aren’t receiving much attention.

Comment: I mean the perimeter of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the $p$-norm. Thanks for the help, Clayton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first question (excluding the trivial cases $p=0$ and $p=1$) 
$$I_p=\int\left(1+p^p t^{(p-1) p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\,dt=t\,\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{(p-1) p};1+\frac{1}{(p-1) p};-p^p t^{(p-1) p}\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)). So,
$$J_p=\int_0^1\left(1+p^p t^{(p-1) p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\,dt=\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{(p-1) p};\frac{p^2-p+1}{(p-1) p};-p^p\right)$$

What is interesting is that $J_p$ goes through a minimum value as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2.00000 \\
 2 & 1.47894 \\
 3 & 1.45510 \\
 4 & 1.49983 \\
 5 & 1.54817 \\
 6 & 1.58972 \\
 7 & 1.62429 \\
 8 & 1.65314 \\
 9 & 1.67752 \\
 10 & 1.69837
\end{array}
\right)$$

Remarkable is $J_2=\frac{10+\sqrt{5} \sinh ^{-1}(2)}{4 \sqrt{5}}$.

For the second integral
$$K_p=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos(t)^{2-p}\sin(t)^2+\sin(t)^{2-p}\cos(t)^2\right)^{\frac 1p}\, dt$$ I have not been able to get anything analytical beside $K_1=\frac 23$ and $K_2=\frac \pi 2$. Numerical integration shows that $K_p \sim p-\frac 12$

Comment: Thanks a lot. That hypergeometric function is really interesting. It's such a coincidence that I was reading about it just a week ago.

Comment: It is also curious that it is undefined for $p=1$, since the integral is clearly equal to $2$.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos. I wanted to mean that the formula cannot be used for such a case. Sorry for the lack of precision of my wording. Cheers.

Comment: It's alright, I get it. Which formula did you use to calculate the integral? I checked at the wiki and found only the Euler integral formula. I couldn't see how you applied it, because I think there has to be a change of variables. I don't see how you did it. I changed variables, taking $u=t^{p(p-1)}$, and what I ended up with is not the same as you.

Comment: OK, I messed up in the process, now I see it.

Comment: How did you find the exact value of $J_2$?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos. For $p=2$, the integrand is just $\sqrt{1+4 t^2}$